# Internet is working but weird behaviour of Captive Portal

Tags: networking, wifi, captive-portal

I am using a small hotspot from one provider that our university gave us with 60GB inside of it.
This one:
[This one: [images](https://www.google.com/search?q=tim+hotspot+modem&sxsrf=ALiCzsbeDvxkGp7Ugg3IG6xna_16p3nIgg:1669826596870&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr-JHprNb7AhUChf0HHTEwALsQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=967&dpr=1)
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohq9Z.png)

I configured the SSID and password of the Wi-Fi from its interface `192.168.1.1` 
Internet is working for browsing etc but

- In some websites, it does not work, it just goes to PROVIDER website
- In Linux envrionment, I cannot install packages or update the system, it is just not working, but the weir thing there is a internet.
- Here how it looks like as a icon, it is not also normal, onrmally it is without a question mark on other networks:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfJOk.png)

Please let me know if you have any idea what might be the issue. I am going crazy, did not find anything useful.

I went to captive portal `192.168.1.1` , provide the password, checked network settings, nothing seems wrong.

```
 linur   pop-os   ~   ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=47.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=49.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=110 time=170 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=110 time=92.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=110 time=216 ms
```

Comment: What is the result of `ping 8.8.8.8`? and of `ping google.com`?

Comment: Everything indicates that although you are connected to the router via wifi, it does not make you a gateway to the Internet (maybe the problem is in the router)

Comment: I don't think this device is called router, it is like a hotspot. I don't know how to troubleshoot this problem.. I edited the post with output of ping